# Chartjs bar-chart displays after the jquery function ends

Tags: jquery, chartjs-2.6.0

I have 3 charts in jQuery function,
`chart2` and `chart3` get displayed but `chart1` displays only after the complete function working  ends. I am not sure why this so and not able to trace the actual issue. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Below is a set of code:

$(function () {

```
// Top Widgets Update


 var current_date_time = new Date().getFullYear()
 +  "-" + String(initial_month()).padStart(2, '0') +"-" +  
 String(new Date().getDate()-7).padStart(2, '0')


//Chart1 and top widget records data collection
var distinctaccounts = document.getElementById('distinctaccounts')
var spinner = document.getElementById("loader");
var map_records = get_distincts_records()
var piechart_bu_values = get_configured_accounts(map_records)
// spinner.style.display = 'block';
var acccount_tables = get_initial_records(current_date_time, currentDate(new Date()),0)
// spinner.style.display='none';
// visualizeData(piechart_bu_values, acccount_tables, current_date_time, spinner);
// var acccount_tables = get_accounts_records(current_date_time, currentDate(new Date()),0)
// visualizeData(piechart_bu_values, acccount_tables, current_date_time, spinner);
var histogram_chart = piechart_bu_values[0];
var table_org_name = groupbyTableRecordsOrg_name(acccount_tables);
var _complete_records = _drcords(table_org_name);
var _notify_records = _complete_records[0];
var event_actioned = _complete_records[1];
event_Records_Top_Widget(event_actioned);
get_time_to_process(acccount_tables);



document.getElementById('dateTimePicker').value = String(new Date().getDate()-7).padStart(2, '0')
    + "-" + monthNames[new Date().getMonth()] + "-" + new Date().getFullYear() + ' - '
    + String(new Date().getDate()).padStart(2, '0')
    + "-" + monthNames[new Date().getMonth()] + "-" + new Date().getFullYear();
document.getElementById('starttimeValue').value = current_date_time;
document.getElementById('endtimeValue').value = currentDate(new Date());

// Chart for presenting the event counts according to the business unit
var histogram_chart_element = document.getElementById('horizontal_chart').getContext('2d');
var line_chart = document.getElementById('line-chart').getContext('2d');
// Make the dashboard widgets sortable Using jquery UI
$('.connectedSortable').sortable({
    placeholder: 'sort-highlight',
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    handle: '.card-header, .nav-tabs',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    zIndex: 999999
});
$('.connectedSortable .card-header, .connectedSortable .nav-tabs-custom').css('cursor', 'move');

//Top BU histogram update
var coloR = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(histogram_chart).length; i++) {
    coloR.push(bgcColor[i]);
}
var histogram_chart = {
    labels: Object.keys(histogram_chart),
    datasets: [
        {
            label: piechart_bu_values[1],
            backgroundColor: coloR,
            data: Object.values(histogram_chart),
        }
    ]
};

var histogram_chart_Options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
        display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
        // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
        enabled: false,

        custom: function (tooltipModel) {
            // Tooltip Element
            var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

            // Create element on first render
            if (!tooltipEl) {
                tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
                tooltipEl.innerHTML = "<table style='font-family: \"Trebuchet MS\", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\n" +
                    "  border-collapse: collapse;\n" +
                    "  width: 100%;border: 1px solid #ddd;\n" +
                    "  padding: 8px;'></table>";
                document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
            }

            // Hide if no tooltip
            if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                return;
            }

            // Set caret Position
            tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
            if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
            } else {
                tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
            }

            function getBody(bodyItem) {
                return bodyItem.lines;
            }

            // Set Text
            if (tooltipModel.body) {
                var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || piechart_bu_values[1];
                var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                var innerHtml = '<thead>';

                titleLines.forEach(function (title) {
                    innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                });
                innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                bodyLines.forEach(function (body, i) {
                    var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                    var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
                    style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                    style += '; border-width: 2px';
                    var span = '<div style="word-wrap: break-word;">';
                    for (accountid in piechart_bu_values[1]) {
                        var data = piechart_bu_values[1][accountid].substring(0, piechart_bu_values[1][accountid].indexOf('['));
                        innerHtml += '<tr><td style="word-break: ' +
                            'break-all; overflow: auto;overflow:scroll;background-color: rgba(161,213,104,0.73);">' +
                            piechart_bu_values[1][accountid].substring(0, piechart_bu_values[1][accountid].indexOf('['))
                            + '(' + piechart_bu_values[0][data] + ')' +
                            ' </td></tr>';

                    }

                });
                innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
            }

            // `this` will be the overall tooltip
            var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

            // Display, position, and set styles for font
            tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
            tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
            tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily;
            tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle;
            tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        }
    }
    // tooltips: {
    //  enabled: true,
    //  mode: 'single',
    //  callbacks: {
    //      label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
    //          return piechart_bu_values[1];
    //      }
    //  }
    // }
};

// This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
```

new Chart(histogram_chart_element, {type: 'pie',data: histogram_chart,options: histogram_chart_Options})

```
// Get Records from Tables
var acccount_table = groupbyMultiple(acccount_tables);
var data = acccount_table;
data = sortBy(data, { prop: "date" });
var salesGraphChart = update_notify_remediate_chart(line_chart, event_actioned, _notify_records);

var ctx = document.getElementById('remediate_notify_whitelist').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = 1000;
ctx.canvas.height = 300;

var cfg = {
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Notify',
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
            borderColor: 'orange',
            data: generateSecondChartControlData(data, 'notify'),
            type: 'line',
            pointRadius: 0,
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            borderWidth: 2
        },
        {
            label: 'Remediate',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderColor: 'green',
            data: generateSecondChartControlData(data,
                'remediate'),
            type: 'line',
            pointRadius: 0,
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            borderWidth: 2
        }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                distribution: 'series',
                offset: true,
                ticks: {
                    major: {
                        enabled: true,
                        fontStyle: 'bold'
                    },
                    source: 'data',
                    autoSkip: true,
                    autoSkipPadding: 75,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    sampleSize: 100
                },
                afterBuildTicks: function (scale, ticks) {
                    var majorUnit = scale._majorUnit;
                    if (ticks == null) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    var firstTick = ticks[0];
                    var i, ilen, val, tick, currMajor, lastMajor;
                    val = moment(ticks[0].value);
                    if ((majorUnit === 'minute' && val.second() === 0)
                        || (majorUnit === 'hour' && val.minute() === 0)
                        || (majorUnit === 'day' && val.hour() === 9)
                        || (majorUnit === 'month' && val.date() <= 3 && val.isoWeekday() === 1)
                        || (majorUnit === 'year' && val.month() === 0)) {
                        firstTick.major = true;
                    } else {
                        firstTick.major = false;
                    }
                    lastMajor = val.get(majorUnit);

                    for (i = 1, ilen = ticks.length; i < ilen; i++) {
                        tick = ticks[i];
                        val = moment(tick.value);
                        currMajor = val.get(majorUnit);
                        tick.major = currMajor !== lastMajor;
                        lastMajor = currMajor;
                    }
                    return ticks;
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Check Count'
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            intersect: false,
            mode: 'index',
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, myData) {
                    var label = myData.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                    if (label) {
                        label += ': ';
                    }
                    label += parseFloat(tooltipItem.value).toFixed(2);
                    return label;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var controlChart = new Chart(ctx, cfg);

// var records_without_date = remove_records(acccount_tables)
var records_without_date = groupbyTableRecords(acccount_tables);
tempTableGlobal = groupbyTableRecordsBYid(acccount_tables);
rawTempTableGlobal = groupbyTableRecordsraw_message(acccount_tables);
get_control_recordsTable(records_without_date);

// Control records chart for datewise yearly records
$("#example1").DataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    rowGroup: {
        // Group by name
        dataSrc: 1
    },
    "order": [[3, "desc"]],
    "aLengthMenu": [10, 15, 20, 25]
});


//Date Range Picker
$('.daterange').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
        // 'Today'       : [moment(), moment()],
        // 'Yesterday'   : [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'),
        moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
    endDate: moment()
}, function (start, end) {

    var lTable = document.getElementById("loginTable");
    lTable.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('starttimeValue').value = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    document.getElementById('endtimeValue').value = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    document.getElementById('dateTimePicker').value = start.format('DD') + "-" +
        start.format('MMMM') + "-" + start.format('YYYY')
        + " - " + end.format('DD') + "-" + end.format('MMMM') + "-" + end.format('YYYY');


    //chart 1 update
    // spinner.style.display = 'block';
    var acccount_tables = get_accounts_records(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    // spinner.style.display = 'none';

    var table_org_name = groupbyTableRecordsOrg_name(acccount_tables);
    var _complete_records = _drcords(table_org_name);
    var _notify_records = _complete_records[0];
    var event_actioned = _complete_records[1];
    event_Records_Top_Widget(event_actioned);
    get_time_to_process(acccount_tables);

    salesGraphChart.data.labels = Object.keys(event_actioned);
    salesGraphChart.data.datasets[0].data = Object.values(event_actioned);
    salesGraphChart.data.datasets[1].data = Object.values(_notify_records);
    salesGraphChart.update();

    //chart 2 control update
    var acccount_table = groupbyMultiple(acccount_tables);
    var data = acccount_table;
    data = sortBy(data, { prop: "date" });
    controlChart.data.datasets[0].data = generateSecondChartControlData(data, 'notify');
    controlChart.data.datasets[1].data = generateSecondChartControlData(data, 'remediate');
    controlChart.update();

    // Disable Table
    $('#example1').DataTable().destroy();

    var records_without_date = groupbyTableRecords(acccount_tables);
    tempTableGlobal = groupbyTableRecordsBYid(acccount_tables);
    rawTempTableGlobal = groupbyTableRecordsraw_message(acccount_tables);
    get_control_recordsTable(records_without_date);

    //Enable Table
    $("#example1").DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "order": [[3, "desc"]],
        "aLengthMenu": [10, 15, 20, 25]
    });


});
```

})

Comment: Without seeing your actual code we cannot answer this question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As required I have pasted the code.